# Binding 200 rows in grid view is very slow

Tags: asp.net

While binding 200 rows with 6 columns in grid view, it is taking too much time. I don't want to use pagination. Please help me to resolve this issue.

I will get the dataset from database in less than 1 sec. But while binding this data to gridview, it is taking too much time(more than 1 minute).

```
DataSet dtStudent = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spGetStudentListForSelectedCourse", new SqlParameter("@courseid", AdClassSchedId), new SqlParameter("@internshipactivityid", activityid));
GRDApprovalStduents.DataSource = dtStudent;
GRDApprovalStduents.DataBind();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Depends entirely how the databinding is done and how many columns do you have etc etc. Edit the question with your code so that it's even possible to give you an answer with some optimization tips. All in all it might also be impossible if the amount of data binded is large, then you don't have many options but paging.

Comment: What is your datasource? If it is database, maybe your query not enough effectively.

Comment: discript your code

Comment: How much time is it taking? How much time does the database query take? Does the database query only return 200 records? Have you tried using F12 profiler to see what's taking all the time?

Comment: put your code and query?